# java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> when using Paths.get()

Tags: java, path

When I use Paths.get() to create a directory I encounter exception below.

```
java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 2: /C:/Users/Desktop/workspaces/sra/emm-be/wsm-kap-api-server/target/test-classes/swagger\swagger.json
```

This happens when I use the workspace of my Windows machine. For linux, it's working fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your directory path contains `/` try using

```
    Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\workspaces\\sra\\emm-be\\wsm-kap-api-server\\target\\test-classes\\swagger\\swagger.json");
```

Comment: i'm trying to build javafx and don't know how to solve this problem

Comment: when / and when to use \\, please explain!!

Comment: "/" is used for defining a Unix path, "\" is used for defining a Windows path. But since "\" is used to escape a character, the "\" character will not be take into account. So escaping the escaping character will take the "\" into account

Answer (score 3):

You have `/` before C in Your directory path. If you remove it it should work on Windows too.

```
 Paths.get(C:/Users/Desktop/workspaces/sra/emm-be/wsm-kap-api-server/target/test-classes/swagger/swagger.json);
```